# Single Meteor application having multiple domains

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, multiple-domains, sites

Is it possible to create a single Meteor application having multiple domains and displaying different views/layouts depending on that domain?

For example, i have a admin interface accessible on ***admin.myapp.com*** and the two domains ***storeX.com*** and ***storeY.com***. Both domains should point to the data from ***admin.myapp.com*** but displaying the data (mostly) independently of each other.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be totally updated to 2014 standards, but I did answer this question before:

[How can Meteor handle multiple Virtual Hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788146/how-can-meteor-handle-multiple-virtual-hosts)

And with the same setup, you can use [Passenger](http://www.phusionpassenger.com) (for `nginx` OR `apache2`) for Meteor. [Here's a complete tutorial for using Passenger with Meteor](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Meteor-tutorial), but keep in mind you have to integrate the multiple virtualhosts/domains to this tutorial yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better approach would be to use Meteor's Pub/Sub capabilities, rather than sharing a DB per say. It's entirely possible to publish and subscribe across meteor apps, or indeed any implementation using DDP.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddp_connect

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [partitioner](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-partitioner) to send different views of the data to different users based on the domain name they hit.

Answer (score 0):

See [How can I share MongoDB collections between Meteor apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115723/how-can-i-share-mongodb-collections-between-meteor-apps) . Basically the idea is that you build two meteor apps which would share the mongodb and collection(s) data.